# How to test as if I was in another geographic location, e.g. opposite US coast?

Tags: performance

We are on the east coast.  How could I test and try and have a west coast experience?

In terms of speed and responsiveness in a browser.

It's not just about throttling down my connection, useful though that is (in Chrome dev tools), it's about a lot of requests going to a fro for stuff like ajax and also trying to see the effects of moving assets onto a CDN but still having the application server in one place.

Comment: how about getting `aws server` in that region for short time?

Comment: hahaha @mark, humor man humor :D